# Uniformly Bounded (updating)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, inequalities, integration

Suppose that $a_1<1$, $a_1+a_2+a_3>1.$ For  $x,y,z>0,$

(1) define a fucntion
$$H(x,y,z)=\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^{a_1}~ (1+t)^{a_2+1}~ 
 (1+t+z)^{a_3}}\exp\big\{-\frac{x}{1+t}-\frac{ y}{1+t+z}\big\}dt }{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^{a_1}~ (1+t)^{a_2}~(1+t+z)^{a_3}}\exp\big\{-\frac{x}{1+t}-\frac{ y}{1+t+z}\big\}dt}.$$
Then $H(x,y,z)$ is uniformly bounded over $x,y$, i.e. there is a constant C, such that
$H(x,y)\le C.$

(2) Furthermore, define 
$$L(y,z)=\frac{y^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^{a_1}~ (1+t)^{a_2}~ 
 (1+t+z)^{a_3+1}}\exp\big\{-\frac{ y}{1+t+z}\big\}dt }{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^{a_1}~ (1+t)^{a_2}~(1+t+z)^{a_3}}\exp\big\{-\frac{y}{1+t+z}\big\}dt}.$$

Then $L(x,y)$ is also uniformly bounded over $x,y.$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to prove uniformly bounded?? Need help.

Comment: There seems to be a typo. In the current version of the question, the numerator of your fraction is just $x^{1/2}$ times the denominator

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I think it is right. The power of (1+t) is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may assume that $x>100(1+|a_2|+|a_3|)^2$, for other $x$ simply $C=10(1+|a_2|+|a_3|)$ works perfectly.

Partition the integral in the numerator onto two parts: $I_1$ over $(0,\sqrt{x}]$ and $I_2$ over $[\sqrt{x},\infty)$. The second part does not exceed the denominator, since $\sqrt{x}(1+t)^{-1}<1$ for all $t\geqslant \sqrt{x}$. It suffices to estimate $I_1\leqslant c I_2$ for some fixed $c>0$ (depending only on $a_1,a_2,a_3$). For this it suffices to prove the pointwise estimate $f(t)\leqslant 2^{a_1} f(2t)$ for all $t\in (0,\sqrt{x})$ where $f$ is the integrated function. Indeed, integrating this over $(0,\sqrt{x})$ we get $\int_0^{\sqrt{x}}f(t)dt\leqslant 2^{a_1}\int_0^{\sqrt{x}}f(2t)dt=2^{a_1-1}\int_0^{2\sqrt{x}} f(t)dt$, thus $I_1(1-2^{a_1-1})\leqslant 2^{a_1-1}I_2$ as desired. We have
$$
\frac{f(t)}{2^{a_1}f(2t)}=\left(\frac{1+2t}{1+t}\right)^{a_2+1}\cdot 
\left(\frac{1+2t+z}{1+t+z}\right)^{a_3}\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{x}{1+2t}\left(\frac{1+2t}{1+t}-1\right)-
\frac{z}{1+2t+z}\left(\frac{1+2t+z}{1+t+z}-1\right)
\right).
$$
We estimate $\frac{1+2t+z}{1+t+z}\leqslant \frac{1+2t}{1+t}$ and use the estimate $1+s\leqslant e^s$ for $s:=\frac{1+2t}{1+t}-1$. Also estimate $-\frac{z}{1+2t+z}\left(\frac{1+2t+z}{1+t+z}-1\right)\leqslant 0$ in the exponent. We get
$$
\frac{f(t)}{2^{a_1}f(2t)}\leqslant \exp\left(\left(1+|a_2|+|a_3|-\frac{x}{1+2t}\right)s\right)\leqslant 1,
$$
since $\frac{x}{1+2t}\geqslant \frac{x}{1+2\sqrt{x}}>\frac13\sqrt{x}>1+|a_2|+|a_3|$ due to our assumptions.

Comment: Your answer is amazing!!!. Applying your method, I try to prove the following similar question. But I failed. Could you help me?

Comment: I have updated the question. Question (2) is similar. I am not sure your method still works. I fail to prove it by your method.

Comment: @xiaopai833 I think, everything works: we break the integral at the point $t_0$ for which $\sqrt{y}/(1+t_0+z)=100A$, where $A=|a_2|+|a_3|+1$, (if such a point does not exist, the ratio is clearly bounded.) On $(0,t_0]$ we estimate the ratio $\frac{f(t)}{2^{a_1}f(2t)}$ using the estimate $(1+2t)/(1+t)\leqslant 1+t\leqslant e^t$. And $tA\leqslant y(\frac1{1+t+z}-\frac1{1+2t+z})=\frac{ty}{(1+t+z)(1+2t+z)}$.

Comment: Yes. Everything still works.

Comment: I have updated the question again. It is a harder problem. I am not sure your method still works. I fail to prove it. I need your help.

Comment: You gave me the answer when $b_1=b_2$. How to prove the general case?

Comment: I am afraid that it is no longer true if say $a_1=1/2,a_2=2,a_3=0$ (I say now about $L$), $b_1=1$, $b_2=100000000$. Then the integral in the denominator over $[0,1]$ looks to be much greater than all three integrals over $[0,1],[1,1+z]$ and $[1+z,\infty)$ in certain regime for $y$ and $1+z$. Within a bounded factor, you may significantly simplify these integrals (say, on $[0,1]$ you replace $1+t$ to 1, $1+t+z$ to $1+z$, $b_1y/(1+t+z)$ to $y/(2+z)$; on $[1,1+z]$ in the denominator you replace $1+t$ to $t$, $1+t+z$ to $z$, $e^{-b_2y/(1+t+z)}$ to $e^{-50y/(1+z)}$ etc.)

Comment: I try to understand your idea: Partition the integral in the denominator onto three parts: $D_1$ over $[0,1]$, $D_2$ over $[1,1+z]$ and $D_3$ over $[1+z,\infty).$ Similarly, the numerator: $N_1$ over $[0,1]$, $N_2$ over $[1,1+z]$ and $N_3$ over $[1+z,\infty).$ Then
$D_1\le C\exp(-\frac{b_2y}{2+z})$, where $C$ is some given constant, the following C omitted; $D_2 \le \exp(-\frac{50y}{1+z})\int_1^{1+z}\frac{1}{t^{2.5}} dt ;$ $N_1\ge \frac{y^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2+z}\exp(-\frac{y}{1+z})$;
$N_2 \ge \frac{y^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2(1+z)} \exp(-\frac{y}{2+z})\int_1^{1+z}\frac{1}{t^{2.5}} dt ;$

Comment: @ Fedor Petrov How to handle $D_3$ and $N_3$, and why you said
"Then the integral in the denominator over $[0,1]$ looks to be much greater than all three integrals over $[0,1]$,$[1,1+z]$ and $[1+z,\infty)$ in certain regime for $y$ and $1+z$"? which mean $D_1\ge D_2$ and $D_1\ge D_3?$ Could you explain in detail?

Comment: Well, $D_3\leqslant \int_{1+z}^\infty t^{-5/2} e^{-1000y/t} dt$, we make the substitution $1000y/t=s$, the integral estimates as $Cy^{-3/2}$. Now take say $y=(1+z)\log(1+z)$ and large $z$. We see that $N_1$ is much larger than $D_1+D_2+D_3$.

Comment: Sorry, $D_3\leqslant (1+z)^{-3/2}$ (ignore the exponent at all), and now choose $y=(1+z)\log(1+z)/10$.

Comment: Yes. Thank you, @Fedor Petrov.

Comment: are you interested in this question? [https://mathoverflow.net/q/325089/134602]